# topic for presentation

Tags: acoustics

guys, i need some help here. i need to give a presentation as a part of my college assignment. can anyone suggest me a topic please. i have thought about Acoustics or 3D audio. but then acoustics would become very theoretical and i don't have enough resources to make a presentation on 3d audio. any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it open-topic and you're choosing to make it audio-based, or does it have to be acoustics related (hence your use of the 'acoustics' tag)?

You could always branch off a little and do something on psychoacoustics or emotional responses to certain sounds, such as discussed in this post [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01dzmbs). You could collect a bunch of sounds and play them out to your audience and see how they react to each, similar to what they did on [this episode of BBC's Bang Goes the Theory](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01dzmbs) . I don't know if you'll be able to hunt down that episode but they've got a link to the sound clips they used. You could then follow up on a discussion as to why we react in such ways etc.

**EDIT:** Or have a look at [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p00q6qnz) on 'sonic crystal'

Answer (score 1):

Maybe on the Loudness Wars of music and labels over the past couple decades. There's enough research material on the web, and you can pull up music examples that showcase it pretty blatantly.

Comment: There's a really obvious example involving a Metallica song. If i remember correctly they released it for guitar hero first and the track had a decent dynamic range, then they released the album and it was maximised to shit.. The game version was actually better and lots of people kicked off about it.

Answer (score 0):

Theres always plenty to talk about when it comes to cross-over. I bet there's enough information out there about the skrillex / korn dubstep thing. Most of it will be subjective, reactionary crap, but I'm sure you can find something.

Answer (score 0):

How about commercialization and monetizing of music/sound/media products that involve sound in the digital era. You could study and present what kind of options there are (digital marketplaces, personal websites, crowd sourcing services etc.) for making money out of sound and what are their differences. Maybe search some data about the state of different sound-related media industries, their structures (companies, independents) and how different groups generate profit. You could throw a few words about promotion and marketing as well.

I personally find technical presentations rather boring, if they aren't given in the right context and/or by the right person (one usually needs good theoretical background to present the stuff in a way that's not too speculative or superficial). And I think the creative side is much more relevant, unless the class/course you're taking part in has a technical "engineering"-like focus.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to have a chance to research and do a talk on how good or bad audio effects the way you perceive visuals. Sight is your strongest sense, but audio effects the way your subconscious interprets the vision.